# Summation of binomial coefficients up to $r$ terms.

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

I wanted to find the sum of the following series :
$$\sum_{k=1}^{r}{{n}\choose{k}}$$
I searched for it in my book but didn't find it. However I was able to find :  $$\sum_{k=1}^{r}{{n}\choose{k}}(-1)^{k}$$
The solution was given as :[image: image1]

When I tried to do the same for the first series I got stuck on :
$$2^{n}-\sum_{k=1}^{n-r}{{n-k}\choose{r}}2^{k-1}$$
I am not able to get any ideas related to this.

So how to proceed further with this approach or is there a better method?

Comment: It is not a *series* (just a finite sum) and given the statement of the central limit theorem that is more or less equivalent to asking if $e^{-x^2/2}$ has a simple primitive.

Comment: I don't think there's any way to write that in a shorter or more usable form. It's not the same as the alternating series. See [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17202/sum-of-the-first-k-binomial-coefficients-for-fixed-n) if you're interested